# Yeoman offers to create a new app instead of using scaffolding

Tags: node.js, yeoman, mean-stack, meanjs, yeoman-generator

I have a meanjs app working and `npm install`ed. I want to add a controller so I do `yo meanjs:crud-module reports`. Instead of getting the questions one should get when creating a controller, it puts me through creating a new meanjs app.

How can I send it to the scaffolding and not the new app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no sub-generator in the last version of generator-meanjs.

You can only generate a full app.

Please refer to the latest documentation https://github.com/meanjs/generator-meanjs

If you need subgenerators, then you'll need to install an old version of generator-meanjs. You can do that with:

```
npm install -g generator-meanjs@~0.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the version of meanjs and version of yeoman generator. In the latest version of the generator they are not including subgenerators. Also crud-module subgenerator is changed to vertical-module.

Comment: There is one version for meanjs app and there is same version for generator-meanjs which is used to generate meanjs app. They are different projects on github. Latest version of generator-meanjs is generating latest version of meanjs app but subgenerators are not developed yet.
You should check what version is your meanjs app and install generator-meanjs for that version (if it is latest there are no subgenerators yet).
If you want to use subgenerators you will need to downgrade the version of the generator-meanjs but it will generate old version of meanjs app.